# How to plot from two dataframe in ggplot2?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
```

first dataframe

```
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(20,0.4,0.2), seq(0,200,by=10)))
df2 <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(30,0.6,0.25), seq(0,270,by=9)))
df1$Source = "df1"
df2$Source = "df2"
df_combined = rbind(df1, df2)
```

plot

```
ggplot(df_combined, aes(x = X1, y = X2, group = 1))+ 
geom_line() + theme_bw()+ facet_grid(rows = vars(Source))
```

second dataframe

```
df_combined1=df_combined
df_combined1$X1=df_combined1$X1+1
df_combined1$X2=df_combined1$X1+2
```

I now I want to add the lines of this second dataframe to the plot of the fist dataframe

Comment: (1) I suggest never do `data.frame(cbind(..))`, just remove the `cbind` and you'll get the same results. If you ever include strings inside of it, then all numbers will be converted to strings, not good. (2) Your `df1` has length-20 and 21, not sure what you intend to happen there. (3) Likely as simple as `+ geom_line(data=df_combined)`, optionally updating `aes`thetics or other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
ggplot(data = df_combined,aes(x = X1, y = X2, group = 1))+ 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_line(data = df_combined1) + 
    theme_bw()+ 
    facet_grid(rows = vars(Source))
```

This will recycle your aes() specification for the second dataset. Looks a bit weird though, I suppose you intended to write:

```
df_combined1$X1=df_combined1$X1+1
df_combined1$X2=df_combined1$X2+2
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
gg_chart <- ggplot(df_combined, aes(x = X1, y = X2, group = 1))+ 
  geom_line() + theme_bw()+ facet_grid(rows = vars(Source))

gg_chart + geom_line(data = df_combined1, aes(x = X1, y = X2), color = "blue")
```